# Appear and zoom when scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML like:

```
<div class='service'>
 <img src='img.png'/>
</div>
```

I used css like :

```
.service img{opacity:0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);}
```

When I scroll down it appears but it does not zoom with `transform`:
I used like:

```
$(this).animate({'opacity':'1','-webkit-transform':'scale(1)'},1000);
```

Can you help me for fixing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the documentation on [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and it doesn't seem like CSS 'scale()' property is supported.

So in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/xaNqW/) I just switched to height and width.

JS

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $('.service img').animate({ 'opacity': '1',
                                  'width': '400',
                                 'height': '450'
                               }, 1000);

});
```